# a jQuery image-group animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a div with three same images.

```
<div>
    <img class="movlights" src="files/images/movelights.png" alt="10 years logo" />
    <img class="movlights sec" src="files/images/movelights.png" alt="10 years logo" />
    <img class="movlights third" src="files/images/movelights.png" alt="10 yearslogo"/>
</div>
```

Each has different "absolute" position in a way that all form a row and their parent div is
overflowed - hidden.

So I animate them moving together simultaneously as a group from left to right with this code:

```
  $(function(){ 
    movelights();
  });

  function movelights(){
    for(x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
       $('div img:eq('+x+')').animate({left: (1400 - x*800)},24000);
    }
  };
```

My problem is:
How to return an image on a certain starting position before the others by queuing it again when it passes the div's right edge so that the animated pattern repeats itself!

So I'm interested in both:

- how to queue image from end of the
  line to beginning
- how to loop the animated pattern

Hope I was clear enough English isn't my native language.

Here's some additional code:

```
div{
width:1000px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

all img{  
  display:block;  
  position:absolute;
  left:120px;  
}
img2{  
  left:-678px;
}
img3{  
  left:-1400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try using `timer = setTimeout(functionname to loop, 0);`.

Whenever I ask a jQuery question someone usually responds with a link to some bloated plugin someone else built. The question was how to do something not where to download something.

Comment: 10x That solution came up to mind but I've figured out another much easier.
I've made a really long div and repeated its background img horizontally and then moved it by animation! Since I needed a same pattern in the first place to move over and over again it worked!